# Vagrant - Ansible - Install PostgreSQL and Postgis

Tags: vagrant, postgresql, ansible

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL and Postgis with Ansible on a Vagrant VM.

The VM is only use locally for local development, so that's why I grant access to databases.

But I'm reaching some issues to install and access to PostgreSQL (didn't reach the step of Postgis yet).

My Vagrant VM is an `ubuntu/jammy64`.

Firstly, I installed PHP on the VM.

Then I try to install PostrgreSQL. In following, my `psql` task to Ansible:

```yaml
---
- name: Install
  apt:
    update_cache: true
    name:
      - bash
      - openssl
      - libssl-dev
      - libssl-doc
      - postgresql
      - postgresql-contrib
      - libpq-dev
      - python3-psycopg2
    state: present

- name: Check if initialized
  stat:
    path: "{{ postgresql_data_dir }}/pg_hba.conf"
  register: postgres_data

- name: Empty data dir
  file:
    path: "{{ postgresql_data_dir }}"
    state: absent
  when: not postgres_data.stat.exists

- name: Initialize
  shell: "{{ postgresql_bin_path }}/initdb -D {{ postgresql_data_dir }}"
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  when: not postgres_data.stat.exists

- name: Start and enable service
  service:
    name: postgresql
    state: started
    enabled: true

- name: Update pg_ident.conf - allow user to auth with postgres
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/postgresql/{{ postgresql_version }}/main/pg_ident.conf"
    insertafter: "# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME"
    line: "user_{{ user }}             {{ user }}               postgres"

- name: Update pg_hba.conf - disable peer for postgres user
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/postgresql/{{ postgresql_version }}/main/pg_hba.conf"
    regexp: "local   all             postgres                                peer"
    line: "#local   all             postgres                                peer"

- name: Update pg_hba.conf - trust all connection
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/postgresql/{{ postgresql_version }}/main/pg_hba.conf"
    regexp: "local   all             all                                     peer"
    line: "local   all             all                                     trust"

- name: Restart
  service:
    name: postgresql
    state: restarted
    enabled: true

- name: "Create database {{ postgresql_db }}"
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ postgresql_user }}"
  postgresql_db:
    name: "{{ postgresql_db }}"
    state: present

- name: "Create user {{ user }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ postgresql_user }}"
  postgresql_user:
    name: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ user }}"
    state: present

- name: "Grant user {{ user }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ postgresql_user }}"
  postgresql_privs:
    type: database
    database: "{{ postgresql_db }}"
    roles: "{{ user }}"
    grant_option: no
    privs: all
  notify: psql restart
```

My vars:

```yaml
---
user: ojirai
postgresql_version: 14
postgresql_bin_path: "/usr/lib/postgresql/{{ postgresql_version }}/bin"
postgresql_data_dir: "/var/lib/postgresql/{{ postgresql_version }}/main"
postgresql_host: localhost
postgresql_port: 5432
postgresql_db: "db_{{ user }}"
postgresql_user: "{{ user }}"
postgresql_password: "{{ user }}"
ansible_ssh_pipelining: true
```

But when I play the Ansible's playbook I'm getting the following feedback:

```
TASK [include_role : psql] *****************************************************

TASK [psql : Install] **********************************************************
ok: [192.168.50.50]

TASK [psql : Check if initialized] *********************************************
ok: [192.168.50.50]

TASK [psql : Empty data dir] ***************************************************
skipping: [192.168.50.50]

TASK [psql : Initialize] *******************************************************
skipping: [192.168.50.50]

TASK [psql : Start and enable service] *****************************************
ok: [192.168.50.50]

TASK [psql : Create database db_ojirai] ****************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was:      Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
fatal: [192.168.50.50]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database: connection to server on socket \"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432\" failed: No such file or directory\n\tIs the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?\n"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.50.50              : ok=20   changed=14   unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Someone suggests me to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546592/is-the-server-running-locally-and-accepting-connections-on-unix-domain-socket but the error persists. I tried with following processes:

- vagrant destroy > export vars (suggested in the post) > vagrant up > ansible deploy
- export vars (suggested in the post) > vagrant reload > ansible deploy
- export vars (suggested in the post) > vagrant destroy > vagrant up > ansible deploy
- vagrant destroy > vagrant up > export vars (suggested in the post) > ansible deploy

Can you, guys, explain to me where is my mistake, please? Is it my PostgreSQL installation which is wrong?

Thanks for your feedbacks!

Comment: No one have an idea? :(